# Firebase Phone Auth Exception: SMS Code has expired in Android Only

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting an issue of Firebase Phone Auth Verification at the time of registration. It was working perfectly at all before a week but just from a week getting this exception even OTP has not expired nor session time out.

Wondering thing is that at the time of registration when I enter a phone number which is not in the entry of **"Firebase Authentication User"** list, OTP received on a phone number automatically detects OTP from the method of firebase itself / also tried with entering manually OTP code within 1 minute and then call to

`auth.signInWithCredential(credential)`

makes entry to **"Firebase Authentication User"** list, it means to verified successfully but at the client side, it throws an exception of **"`The SMS code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again`"**

This issue also came in the project's web version 1 week ago but after a day it was automatically resolved without any changes.

I checked for iOS version too but it works perfectly but just in Android only when tries to verify the OTP by auto-detection or manually, it gives this error only.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue here? This issue suddenly started happening on our iOS version even though we didn't make any changes.